# Applying repmat to each row of a matrix in Matlab with different inputs

Tags: matlab

I want to stack each row of a matrix A in Matlab a **different** number of times according to what is reported in the vector `count`. To do that I use `repmat` in the following way:

```
counts=[524282; 524286; 524283; 524290];
A=randn(4,19); 
f=@() cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) repmat(A(x,:),counts(x),1), 1:size(counts,1), 'UniformOutput', 0)');
timeit(f)
```

The code takes approx 0.45 sec.

Would you be able to suggest anything faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `repelem` to repeat each element in the initial matrix a particular number of times

```
result = reshape(repelem(A(:), repmat(counts(:), size(A, 2), 1)), [], size(A, 2));
```

**Explanation**

```
A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
counts = [1, 3, 2];
```

`repelem` (for vector inputs), repeats the ith element of the first input the number of times specified in the corresponding element of the second input.

```
repelem([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1])
%     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     3
```

Since `repelem` only supports vector inputs, we flatten `A` into a column vector using `A(:)`. We also then need to craft the second input (the number of times to repeat each element of `A`) such that we repeat `counts` for each column of `A`.

```
nTimes = repmat(counts(:), size(A, 2), 1)
```

We then use `repelem` to perform the repetition

```
repeated = repelem(A(:), nTimes);
```

We then reshape the result to have the correct number of columns

```
reshape(repeated, [], size(A, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution base on `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
co = size(A,2);
A_diff=diff([zeros(1,co);A]);
idx=cumsum([1;counts(1:end-1)]);
result=zeros(sum(counts),co);
result(idx,:)=A_diff;
result = cumsum(result)
```

The idea is using cumsum we can reconstruct a vector form the first difference of it.

```
a=[5 3 2 4];
d=  diff([0 a]);
out = cumsum(d)
```

So `out` is equal to `a`.

We can make a matrix all of zeros of the desired size:

```
result=zeros(sum(count),co);
```

we should find indices of rows of each section

```
idx=cumsum([1;count(1:end-1)]);
```

set the first row of each section to first difference of the matrix `A`

```
A_diff=diff([zeros(1,co);A]);
result(idx,:)=A_diff;
```

so

```
A = randi(4,4,7);
count=[3 ;4 ;2 ;5];
A =

   2   1   4   2   1   3   1
   2   3   2   4   4   3   2
   1   3   1   4   1   2   1
   2   3   2   2   3   1   2

A_diff =

   2   1   4   2   1   3   1
   0   2  -2   2   3   0   1
  -1   0  -1   0  -3  -1  -1
   1   0   1  -2   2  -1   1

result =

   2   1   4   2   1   3   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   2  -2   2   3   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  -1   0  -1   0  -3  -1  -1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   1  -2   2  -1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

apply `cumsum` to it to get the desired result

```
result = cumsum(result)
result =

   2   1   4   2   1   3   1
   2   1   4   2   1   3   1
   2   1   4   2   1   3   1
   2   3   2   4   4   3   2
   2   3   2   4   4   3   2
   2   3   2   4   4   3   2
   2   3   2   4   4   3   2
   1   3   1   4   1   2   1
   1   3   1   4   1   2   1
   2   3   2   2   3   1   2
   2   3   2   2   3   1   2
   2   3   2   2   3   1   2
   2   3   2   2   3   1   2
   2   3   2   2   3   1   2
```